# Is there any alternate similar to NameValueCollection collection in C#

Tags: c#

NameValueCollection can hold multiple string values under a single key.

Is there any collection where I can hold multiple OBJECT (not string) under a single key?

Comment: Dictionary<string, List<object>> ?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List<T>>` ?

Comment: ok, then I need to check for key existence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the `MultiDictionary` in the [corefxlab repository](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/5e1cdeba80d439ffaf7ca49809b95fb792a427fc/src/System.Collections.Generic.MultiValueDictionary). Install the  [`Microsoft.Experimental.Collections` Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/):

```
MultiDictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new MultiDictionary<string, int>();
myDictionary.Add("key", 1);
myDictionary.Add("key", 2);
myDictionary.Add("key", 3);
//myDictionary["key"] now contains the values 1, 2, and 3
```

You can read the following post about the MultiDictionary: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/06/20/would-you-like-a-multidictionary/

Comment: Also see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` if you don't need mutability - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx (via [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx)).

It also means you don't need to check for key existence - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292716(v=vs.110).aspx :

> If the key is not found in the collection, an empty sequence is
>   returned.